# Thymeleaf change button on submit with javascript

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table with students, and each student a button `buttonStud`. To access these buttons I gave them an individual id of the button name + student id using thymeleaf `th:id="'buttonStud'+${student.studentId}"`
Now after I click this button (which is a submit button, inside a form) I want it to change its text..
I wrote this javascript function to change the button, and I pass it the student Id to change the correct button

```
                        function changeButton(studentId) {
                             btn = document.getElementById("'buttonStud'+studentId");
                             btn.innerHTML = 'some text...';
                             btn.disabled=true;
                        }
```

And I think this function will get triggered when I press the submit button (buttonStud button)
so I've made a th:onsubmit for the `<form>`,

```
<form action="/action" object=student method="POST" th:onsubmit="|changeButton('*{student.studentId}');|" />
```

But it is not working, console says "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null". and I think the problem is with the thymeleaf's inside the form. What is the correct thymeleaf writing?

I've checked the console and the name for the button is put corectly, the function is called after i press submit, but i cannot get the element id in `document.getElementById("'buttonStud'+studentId");`- it says its null
How should I write it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem realtes actually to Javascript, not Thymeleaf. The reason for the null reference is a wrong selector. It should be `document.getElementById('buttonStud'+studentId);`. Note the missing double quotes.

The reason would be that JS dosen't use double quotes to do string interpolation in `"'buttonStud'+studentId"` so the result of that would be literally the characters `'buttonStud'+studentId` instead of expected result of `buttonStud1`.